# Can I set self to something such that it gets ignored?

Tags: python

I am working on code using code in a Python class.
For example, something like this:

```
    self.ulist = {}
    for i in self.vlist:
        if i not in self.ulist:
            self.ulist[i] = {}
            self.ulist[i]['appears'] = []
```

The way that I test my code is sometimes I just want to copy the code snippet into Jupyter or ipython and just run the code.

What can I set self to such that it does not give a

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

error? I know that you can set self to anything since self is a variable, could we set 'self' to something such that it ignores it, and treats variables `self.ulist, self.vlist` as `ulist, vlist`?

Comment: Why not just delete `self.`?

Comment: Use Ctrl+H and remove `self.`.

Comment: `self` refers to current instance of class in methods defined in that class.  Did you declare a `class`

Comment: @RedCricket `self` is just a variable, nothing more. It is conventionally the name give to the first argument of a function that will be called as a method. the OP wants to be able to paste a snippet, presumably from some method in a class, into a repl and run it

Comment: I have been removing self by just using the replace. Was just wondering, for curiosity, if there was a value that self could be set to such that the self. part gets ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, any user-defined object will do (that doesn't define a `__slots__`). Python user-defined objects will happily accept any attribute you wish to assign to them. Alternatively you could just use a `SimpleNamespace` object, too:

```
In [1]: from types import SimpleNamespace

In [2]: self = SimpleNamespace()

In [3]:     self.vlist = {}
   ...:     for i in self.vlist:
   ...:         if i not in self.ulist:
   ...:             self.ulist[i] = {}
   ...:             self.ulist[i]['appears'] = []
   ...:

In [4]: self
Out[4]: namespace(vlist={})
```

Which at least has a nice printed representation out of the box.

But again, you could always just do:

```
In [5]: class Foo: pass

In [6]: self = Foo()

In [7]:     self.vlist = {}
   ...:     for i in self.vlist:
   ...:         if i not in self.ulist:
   ...:             self.ulist[i] = {}
   ...:             self.ulist[i]['appears'] = []
   ...:

In [8]: self
Out[8]: <__main__.Foo at 0x105fde048>

In [9]: self.vlist
Out[9]: {}
```

Comment: I just meant that self could be any variable. Thanks for this answer!